# Is this multiplication technically possible?

Tags: java, c++

I have 2 matrices with doubles 200,000x3,000 and 3,000x200,000. They are dense and most values (80%) are filled.

How many iterations are needed for this?

Comment: No, because the number of columns of the first matrix has to match the number of rows of the second. You could multiply one by the transpose of the other, though.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, transpose is acceptable.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @clcto It might take way too long to calculate.

Comment: There is only one way for you to know the answer to your question: just try it. You'll probably get the answer before anyone posts an answer here.

Comment: As far as I know the fastest multiplication algorithms are in O(n^{2.x}) with x somewhere between 2 and 4 if I remember correctly. That should give you a rough idea.

Comment: @yellowantphil  yes

Comment: [Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) is O(nmp), so definitely doable with these dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive algorithm will take [O(200,000 * 3,000 * 200,000)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra), i.e. O(120,000,000,000,000) which is 120 trillion operations, so it will probably take a while.

The operands will each take about 4.5 GB whereas the output matrix will require about 298 GB, assuming 8 bytes per double.

It is not straightforward to compare [Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Implementation_considerations) to the naive algorithm as:

> Furthermore, there is no need for the matrices to be square. Non-square matrices can be split in half using the same methods, yielding smaller non-square matrices. If the matrices are sufficiently non-square it will be worthwhile reducing the initial operation to more square products, using simple methods which are essentially O ( n<sup>2</sup> ). For instance:
>
> - A product of size [2N x N] * [N x 10N] can be done as 20 separate [N x N] * [N x N] operations, arranged to form the result;
> - A product of size [N x 10N] * [10N x N] can be done as 10 separate [N x N] * [N x N] operations, summed to form the result.
>
> These techniques will make the implementation more complicated, compared to simply padding to a power-of-two square; however, it is a reasonable assumption that anyone undertaking an implementation of Strassen, rather than conventional, multiplication, will place a higher priority on computational efficiency than on simplicity of the implementation.

See also [Adaptive Strassen’s Matrix Multiplication](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.7754&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: If I used Strassen algorithm?